# JVM crashes during JMagick readImage

Tags: java, imagemagick, native-code, jvm-crash, jmagick

While trying to use Jmagick to convert image to jpg format, the JVM crashed and this is the report. any suggestions how to figure out how we can fix the issue with Jmagick or anything to resolve this.

JVM crash report

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f204d9987f8, pid=7107, tid=139775491942144
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x1287f8]  __nss_hosts_lookup+0x16848
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

```
Current thread (0x00007f2010140000):  JavaThread "MEDIASERVICE-TRANSCODING-EXECUTOR-5" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7614, stack(0x00007f20047ba000,0x00007f20048bb000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGBUS: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (BUS_ADRERR), si_addr=0x00007f2025303000
```

Registers:

```
RAX=0x00000000028dacd8, RBX=0x00000000058d8a10, RCX=0x0000000000008000, RDX=0x00000000000007f5
RSP=0x00007f20048b14d8, RBP=0x000000000000287d, RSI=0x00007f2025302f88, RDI=0x00000000028dcc60
R8 =0x00000000028dacd8, R9 =0x00007f204d9987d0, R10=0x00007f204dbf5eb0, R11=0x00007f204d9c4970
R12=0x00000000028dacd8, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x00007f204d9987f8, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
```

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f20048b14d8)

```
0x00007f20048b14d8:   00007f2014205c05 0000000002e549d8
0x00007f20048b14e8:   00007f20048b1ee0 00000000031c3320
0x00007f20048b14f8:   00007f200cc6846f 0000000000000760
0x00007f20048b1508:   00007f20048b1ee0 0000000002e549d8
0x00007f20048b1518:   00007f200f68ef96 00007f204dbf5ec8
0x00007f20048b1528:   00007f20048b1ee0 00000000000053a0
0x00007f20048b1538:   0000007300000760 00000000000053d0
0x00007f20048b1548:   0000053b00000120 00000000020e4380
0x00007f20048b1558:   00007f20048b1ee0 0000000000000002
0x00007f20048b1568:   00000000031c3320 00007f20101200e0
0x00007f20048b1578:   000000000c2b3b98 000000000c2b6b98
0x00007f20048b1588:   00007f200f68c78d 00007f20048b1ee0
0x00007f20048b1598:   0000000000000001 00007f20048b1ee0
0x00007f20048b15a8:   00007f20101200e0 000000000c2b3b98
0x00007f20048b15b8:   00007f200f685577 0000000000000001
0x00007f20048b15c8:   0000000002e549c0 00007f20048b1ee0
0x00007f20048b15d8:   00007f200f68580b 0000000000000002
0x00007f20048b15e8:   00007f20048b1ee0 00007f20101200e0
0x00007f20048b15f8:   000000000000000f 0000000000000010
0x00007f20048b1608:   00007f200cc698ff 0000000100000001
0x00007f20048b1618:   00007f2000000001 00007f2000000001
0x00007f20048b1628:   00007f20048b1cc0 0000000000000010
0x00007f20048b1638:   00007f20048b1e78 00007f20048b1cd0
0x00007f20048b1648:   00007f204d8b3809 00007f1fbc87b938
0x00007f20048b1658:   0000000000000013 00000000058d8a10
0x00007f20048b1668:   000000000c2b3a50 00007f20048b92f0
0x00007f20048b1678:   00007f20048b1a10 00007f20048b1950
0x00007f20048b1688:   00007f20048b1a20 0000000000000014
0x00007f20048b1698:   0000000000000067 0000000000000020
0x00007f20048b16a8:   0000000000000067 00007f2044e300e0
0x00007f20048b16b8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f20048b16c8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
```

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f204d9987f8)

```
0x00007f204d9987d8:   28 4e f8 0f 28 56 08 0f 28 5e 18 0f 28 66 28 0f
0x00007f204d9987e8:   28 6e 38 0f 28 76 48 0f 28 7e 58 44 0f 28 46 68
0x00007f204d9987f8:   44 0f 28 4e 78 48 8d b6 80 00 00 00 66 45 0f 3a
0x00007f204d998808:   0f c8 08 44 0f 29 4f 70 66 44 0f 3a 0f c7 08 44
```

Register to memory mapping:

```
RAX=0x00000000028dacd8 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000058d8a10 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000008000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000000000007f5 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f20048b14d8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f2010140000
RBP=0x000000000000287d is an unknown value
RSI=0x00007f2025302f88 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000028dcc60 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000000028dacd8 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007f204d9987d0: <offset 0x1287d0> in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at 0x00007f204d870000
R10=0x00007f204dbf5eb0: <offset 0x385eb0> in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at 0x00007f204d870000
R11=0x00007f204d9c4970: <offset 0x154970> in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at 0x00007f204d870000
R12=0x00000000028dacd8 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
```

Stack:

```
[0x00007f20047ba000,0x00007f20048bb000],  sp=0x00007f20048b14d8,  free space=989k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x1287f8]  __nss_hosts_lookup+0x16848
```

Java frames:

```
(J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  magick.MagickImage.readImage(Lmagick/ImageInfo;)V+0
j  magick.MagickImage.<init>(Lmagick/ImageInfo;)V+11
j  com.app.mediaservice.transcoding.task.image.ImageTranscodeTask.doTranscode(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/io/File;Ljavax/activation/MimeType;Lcom/app/mediaservice/MediaObjectType;)[B+48
j  com.app.mediaservice.transcoding.task.TranscodeCallable.call()Lcom/app/mediaservice/MediaObjectRendition;+69
j  com.app.mediaservice.transcoding.task.TranscodeCallable.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42
J  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Detailed report uploaded:http://pastebin.com/XzFTUBtX

**Code**

```
File inputFile = <Some file copied to tmp folder>
ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    MagickImage magickImage = new MagickImage(info);

    try {
        magickImage = ImageThumbnail.createThumbnail(magickImage, targetMediaObjectType);
        magickImage.setFileName(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        magickImage.writeImage(info);
    } catch (MagickException e) {
        LOG.error(String.format("Transcoding of Image failed %s->%s", original.getMimeType(), targetType), e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        magickImage.destroyImages();
    }



public static MagickImage createThumbnail(MagickImage magickImage, MediaObjectType targetMediaObjectType) throws MagickException {

    magickImage.setImageFormat("JPEG");

    magickImage.setQuality(50);
    magickImage.profileImage("*", null);

    switch (some logic) {
    case crop:
        magickImage = magickImage.scaleImage(newWidth, newHeiht);
        Rectangle chopInfo = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
        magickImage = magickImage.cropImage(chopInfo);
        break;
    case resize:
        magickImage = magickImage.scaleImage(newWidth, newHeight);
        break;
    }
    return magickImage;
}
```

Comment: care to share your code - also, just curious - have you tried using im4java instead?

Comment: @alihaider... we haven't tried im4java .

Comment: care to share the code (unless I missed it)

Comment: code added to the question above

Comment: try re-running with -Xint, although I don't think it'll help in this case

Comment: Looks like a bug in native code. Install debug versions of everything (imagemagick and libc6) and run the program under a debugger such as `gdb`. This is a long shot, but seeing that it crashes in `nss_hosts_lookup`, what do have in `/etc/hosts`?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's getting old. I run into this exact problem today. It turns out you just need to do what JVM told you to do in the error message.

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

It actually removes a limit on core resources usage set in your system. After that it should solve the problem.